# Removing ExecControl to upgrade to Ratpack v1.1.1?

Tags: ratpack

I am learning Ratpack and working from multiple resources.  I have the following interface and class that works in Ratpack v0.9.18 but fails in v1.1.1 because of removal of the ExecControl interface.

```
//file: src/main/groovy/app/UserService.groovy
package app
import ratpack.exec.Promise
interface UserService {
  Promise<Void> save (User user)
  Promise<List<User>> getUsers ()
}

//file: src/main/groovy/app/DefaultUserService.groovy
package app
import ratpack.exec.ExecControl
import ratpack.exec.Promise
class DefaultUserService implements UserService {
  private final List storage = []
  @Override
  Promise<Void> save (User user) {
    storage << user
    ExecControl.current ().promiseOf (null)
  }
  @Override
  Promise<List<User>> getUsers () {
    ExecControl.current ().promiseOf (storage)
  }
}
```

I thought that changing the line with ExecControl with:

```
Promise.of (storage)
```

would work but results in

```
MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static ratpack.exec.Promise.of() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList).
```

The Promise.of () method is expecting a type of ratpack.exec.Upstream.

How should the above DefaultUserService class be modified to work with Ratpack v1.1.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Promise.of(Upstream)` http://ratpack.io/manual/current/api/ratpack/exec/Promise.html#of-ratpack.exec.Upstream- is a way to signal the result of some process to downstream consumers. You can signal whether or not something completed successfully via `Downstream#error(Throwable)` or `Downstream#success(value)` http://ratpack.io/manual/current/api/ratpack/exec/Downstream.html

You can also create a `Promise` from a known value via `Promise.value(value)`

In addition to `Promise` Ratpack also provides `ratpack.exec.Operation` which is like a `Promise<Void>` in that it represents async work with no return type.

I've put together a sample to demonstrate the various ways to create a representation of async work.

```
@Grab('io.ratpack:ratpack-groovy:1.1.1')

import ratpack.exec.Operation
import ratpack.exec.Promise
import ratpack.handling.Context

import ratpack.jackson.Jackson

import static ratpack.groovy.Groovy.ratpack

class User { String name }

class UserService {
    private final List<User> storage = []

    Operation save(User user) {
        storage << user
        Operation.noop()
    }

    Promise<List<User>> getUsers() {
        Promise.of { downstream -> downstream.success(storage) }
        // or
//      Promise.value(storage)
    }
}
ratpack {
    bindings {
        bindInstance new UserService()
    }
    handlers {
        get { Context ctx, UserService userService ->
            userService.getUsers()
                    .map(Jackson.&json)
                    .then(ctx.&render)
        }
        get('add/:name') { UserService userService ->
            userService.save(new User(name: pathTokens.get('name')))
                    .then { render 'User saved' }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some sample curl commands I've executed against this:

```
$ curl localhost:5050
[]

$ curl localhost:5050/add/dan
User saved

$ curl localhost:5050/
[{"name":"dan"}]

$ curl localhost:5050/add/luke
User saved

$ curl localhost:5050/
[{"name":"dan"},{"name":"luke"}]
```